# boost pointer container insert (ptr_list)

Tags: c++, stl, boost, pointer-container

For some reason, I cannot get ptr_list to insert elements.

```
boost::ptr_list<int> somelist;
int *someint = new int(123);
int *someint2 = new int(456);
somelist.push_back(someint);
boost:: ptr_list<int>::iterator i = somelist.begin();

somelist.insert(i,someint2);
```

Any help, please?

Comment: You snippet compiles fine for me. What's the error message?

Comment: could you, please, tell what headers did you include?

Could not find a match for 'boost::ptr_sequence_adapter<int,_STL::list<void *,_STL::allocator<void *> >,boost::heap_clone_allocator>::insert<InputIterator>(boost::void_ptr_iterator<_STL::_List_iterator<void *,_STL::_Nonconst_traits<void *> >,int>,int *)'

Comment: well, I guess it is specific problem of an old compiler I use (borland c++ builder 6). Downloading right now a new version to check if it solves my problem.

Comment: I've included `boost/ptr_container/ptr_list.hpp`.

Comment: You should probably write the solution as an answer and accept it, so that the question doesn't remain unanswered. It would be wasted work for people looking for unanswered questions.

Answer (score 2):

Some update. After spending another 24 hours on this, I figured out that Borland C++ Builder 6 (very old one 2002) is more compatible with boost 1.39 than a brand new C++ Builder 2009.
But neither of them seem to like pointer containers.

Right now I regret that I did not start this project in MSVC but this is what I have.

So if anyone knows how to use pointer containers with C++ Builder, please, share this information. For me this question is still unresolved.

Switched back to `std::list<boost::shared_pointer>`

Comment: some update. Newest version of boost in the SVN trunk seems to have a lot of fixes for Borland and gives to access to more components but still errors with pointer containers.